# Why are string literals not rvalues

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, lvalue

Consider this code:

```cpp
void test(auto& arg){}

int main(){
    test("bla");
    test(1);
}
```

The call `test(1);` gives an error, because `1` is an rvalue

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:50:14: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int&' to an rvalue of type 'int'
   50 |         test(1);
      |              ^
main.cpp:37:17: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void test(auto:1&) [with auto:1 = int]'
   37 | void test(auto& arg){}
```

Why isn't this the case for `test("bla");`? Shouldn't this be an r-value as well?

Comment: _"...String literals have static storage duration, and thus exist in memory for the life of the program...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal .  So they can't be an expiring value.

Comment: Also _"The following expressions are lvalue expressions:..."_ ... _"...a string literal, such as "Hello, world!";"_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: Too many exceptions to the rules. Thank you.

Comment: `1` is an integer literal, not a character literal. Although, to be fair, a character literal would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> test("bla");
> ```

The type of this string literal is `const char[4]`

So you were actually calling:

```
void test(const char (&arg)[4]){}
```

The `arg` is const-qualified here, so if you change `arg` in this function body, you will also get a compile error.

Comment: The type - yes, but what matters here is the value category.