# What's causing the error in this example using a const rvalue reference parameter?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

Using this program:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

static std::ostringstream oss;

struct fmt
{
  template <typename T>
  fmt& operator<< (const T&& val)
  {
    oss << val;
    return *this;
  }
};

int main()
{
  fmt() << "123";
  std::cout << oss.str();
}
```

Visual Studio 2919 gives me this:

```
$ cl /EHsc rref.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30151 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

rref.cpp
rref.cpp(18): error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [4]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
rref.cpp(9): note: could be 'fmt &fmt::operator <<<char[4]>(const T (&&))'
        with
        [
            T=char [4]
        ]
rref.cpp(18): note: while trying to match the argument list '(fmt, const char [4])'
```

If I use only `T&& val` (without "const") all goes well.

I can't understand the cause of the error.

What's the cause of the error, and how to fix it ?

Comment: That's a template function, so it's a _forwarding reference_, not an rvlaue reference.

Comment: [Do rvalue references to const have any use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4938875/7143595) The point to use rvalues is to be able  to move them, so a const rvalue reference is a weird thing.

Comment: @MatG it's not an rvalue reference.

Comment: For a template T, `T&&` is a forwarding reference that binds to anything. `const T&&` is not a forwarding reference but a const rvalue. It doesn't bind to the lvalue you pass.

Comment: @doug

now I see that I don't really want a forwarding reference here ... 

but,  in `fmt() << "123";`, isn't "123" a const rvalue ?
I would think so

Comment: See [Why are string literals not rvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847717/why-are-string-literals-not-rvalues)

Comment: *"how to fix it ?"* -- Doesn't the answer to this appear earlier in the question (*"If I use only `T&& val` (without 'const') all goes well."*)? It seems to me the question should simply be *"What's the cause of the error?"*

Comment: @BoP good one, now I understand some stange errors that sometimes I see, related to string literals ("...", no "..."s)

Comment: @TobySpeight It's not a forwarding reference due to the presence of `const`

Comment: Related: [Why does adding const turn a forwarding reference into an rvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38814939/5740428)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string literal such as `"123"` is an lvalue expression, but you declared the `operator<<` overload to accept only rvalues (because it takes a `const` rvalue reference). You can't bind a rvalue reference (whether or not it is `const`) to a lvalue.

It should be `const T& val` instead of `const T&& val`. A `const` lvalue reference can bind to both lvalues and rvalues.

Maybe you wanted `val` to be a forwarding reference instead which can be deduced to either a lvalue reference or a rvalue reference, but that only makes sense if you actually forward it in the body with `std::forward`.

`const T&&` is however not a forwarding reference and the special deduction rules do not apply to it. It will always be deduced to a `const` rvalue reference. Only a function parameter with a type which consists of a template parameter directly applied with `&&` constitutes a forwarding reference with the special deduction rules.

In general `const` in combination with `&&` is usually useless, except in certain situations to make overload sets not accept rvalue arguments (by `= delete`ing the overload).

Comment: I remember Scott Meyer making a big issue of "universal references" ... from the comments above I realize now that they're the same as "forwarding references" ... what I really needed was "const T& val", but for whatever reason I ended up trying "const T&& val", which didn't work ... anyway, now I know (more or less) what "universal/forwarding" references are used for

Comment: @zentrunix Scott Meyer used the term "_universal reference_" for them first, but the standard now uses the term "_forwarding reference_". Both terms do indeed refer to the exact same thing.